# Disordered fields on custom OpenERP module

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo

I got these fiels declared in this order on my module.py

```
class certificados(osv.osv):

_name = 'certificados.certificados'
_description = "Certificados de No Produccion"
_inherit=['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

_columns = {
    'Registro_Numero' : fields.integer('Registro Numero'),
    'Fecha_de_Emision': fields.date('Fecha de Emision', required=True, select=True),
    'Fecha_de_Solicitud': fields.date('Fecha de Solicitud', required=True, select=True),
    'Fecha_del_Documento': fields.date('Fecha del Documento', required=True, select=True),
    'Vigencia' : fields.integer('Vigencia'), 'cert_ids' : fields.one2many('certificados.line', 'requisicion_id','Items del Certificado'),
    'descripcion' : fields.text('Descripcion'),
    'notas' : fields.text('Notas'),
}


class certificados_line(osv.osv):

_name = 'certificados.line'
_description = "Certificados No Produccion line"

def multi_a_b(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context):
        res[record.id] = record.Cantidad * record.Precio_Unitario_Declarado
    return res

_columns = {
    'Codigo_Arancelario' : fields.integer('Codigo Arancelario'),
    'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Material'),
    'Descripcion_Arancelaria' : fields.char('Descripcion Arancelaria', size=42, required = True, translate = True), 
    'Especificaciones_Tecnicas' : fields.char('Especificaciones Tecnicas', size=60, required = True, translate = True), 
    'Cantidad' : fields.float('Cantidad'), 'Unidad_de_Medida': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Unidad de Medida'),
    'Precio_Unitario_Declarado' : fields.float('Precio Unitario Declarado'), 'Moneda' : fields.many2one('res.currency', 'Moneda'),
    'Valor_En_Divisas' : fields.function(multi_a_b, type='integer', string='Valor En Divisas'),
    'requisicion_id' : fields.many2one('certificados.certificados', 'Certificados de No Produccion', ondelete='cascade'),
    'Cantidad_Consumida' : fields.float('Cantidad Consumida'), 'Cantidad_Disponible' : fields.float('Cantidad Disponible'),
}

certificados_line()
```

On my module_view.xml, i load the `'certificados.line'` class, with a field in `'certificados.certificados` called `cert_ids` , as you can see in the code above.

Problem is, that when i load the `certificados.line` fields, i do it in a specific order, but seems like the xml somehow doesn't cares about that, and takes the `cert_ids` fields randomly.

This is the module_view.xml interesting code

```
<record id="student_certificados_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">certificados.result.form</field>
        <field name="model">certificados.certificados</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Introducir los datos" version="7.0">
                <sheet>
                    <div class="oe_edit_only">
                        <label for="Registro_Numero" class="oe_inline"/>
                    </div>
                    <h1>
                        <field name="Registro_Numero" class="oe_inline"/>
                    </h1>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="Fecha_de_Emision"/>
                            <field name="Fecha_de_Solicitud"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="Fecha_del_Documento"/>
                            <field name="Vigencia"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Productos">
                            <field name="cert_ids">
                                <tree string="Productos">
                                    <field name="product_id"/>
                                    <field name="Codigo_Arancelario"/>
                                    <field name="Descripcion_Arancelaria"/>
                                    <field name="Especificaciones_Tecnicas"/>
                                    <field name="Cantidad"/>
                                    <field name="Precio_Unitario_Declarado"/>
                                    <field name="Valor_En_Divisas"/>
                                    <field name="Cantidad_Consumida"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                            <separator string="Observaciones"/>
                            <field name="descripcion"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
                <div class="oe_chatter">
                    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                </div> 
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Seems like it doesn't matters if i put inside `cert_ids` the fields in a specific order, it loads ALL of the fields in `certificados.line` class, in a random way, somebody could shed some light upon this?

I hope i have explained myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define a view for the model `certificados_line`.You have defined a tree view for the model `*certificados_line*` inside `*student_certificados_form*`. but not a form view. you have have to add a form view here inside `*student_certificados_form*` or a new form view for the model `*certificados_line*`

Comment: True, i'll define it after the tree... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

user `_order_by :` in class `certificados_line` to list data in specific order of a field.

Comment: Thanks! But _order_by and what is the attribute?

Comment: any field by which you want to maintain order of the list.